# Laravel Events Dynamic Channel Name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, websocket, real-time, pusher

I am creating a real-time notifications feature within my app that will use Pusher to automatically notify the user when they get a notification (which is created by certain actions taken by users they follow).

I know how to set up the event and have it broadcast, but I'm confused as to the channels to broadcast these notifications on. The situation will be user A follows many other users, but also has many followers himself.

If user A posts new content, we can trigger an event that broadcasts a notification to all of his followers that he just posted something. The question here is, do we broadcast this channel on "user.A"? That means every other user that follows user A will have to subscribe to that channel all the time along with the channels of every other user they follow.

So, what's more efficient, to dynamically broadcast across possibly hundreds of different channels (each channel representing one of user A's followers) OR should each user automatically listen to the channels of possibly hundreds of different users?

Not sure which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First, simplicity and potentially the 'how-to'. In the example, that the OP gave typically instead of what I would consider something like a 'Unique Event Subscription' vs one channel for many events. This does depend on use case and matters of scale. I would assume the typical use case that creating a in-house single channel event listening approach would be best. This being that basically the messages passed are the event types and the data is that stored in an event model (not laravel's but proprietary). This has the major advantages in that you can leverage enums, flexibility, etc... while maintaining simplicity. However, and to the second thought is pricing and such...

Second thought, is that even since the time that this was posted pusher has a cap on the amount of users allowed to be concurrently and actively listening on that socket driven by PersonA in the given example. I believe that number to be 100. While my first point may maintain a simpler in-house approach cost does play a factor. So even if pusher did not cap the active concurrent users the amount events generated and sent are coupled to the amount of active users. Therefore, if a user wasn't too popular and only had 3 followers, but 100k people are on that active socket to update 3 people costs 100k messages in terms of billing. I will share an image to confirm that thought...

[image]

Last point, which has been resolved since the OP originally asked their question was the introduction of presence channels. The give the ability to show activity via whispering etc. They are also more based or geared to the sharing of subscribed "entity" data information, like user or business etc... Versus being built for handling message/event types with data and handling those responses with data learned in real-time. (I stated that last line oddly to keep in mind if data can be found in the DB or backend, it reduces the drive and need for real-time notification or broadcasted events.

Other alternatives for broadcasting that may have different rules are BeyondCode WebSocket Server (https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets), Ably (https://ably.com/), and Soketi (https://docs.soketi.app/). Also others can be found https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#open-source-alternatives